# Using a fragment from a library (android)

Tags: java, android, user-interface, fragment

So I'm building a library in which I've decided to regroup some basic behaviour into a fragment, so the final user won't have to rewrite a lot of code to build an UI that would always do the same things.
The problem is, if my library has resources (layout files), it will generate some .java files (like R.java), which I can't seem to include in the library.
Indeed, when I use the .jar created by the library project, I have access to every functions of it, but it crashes when trying to inflate the fragment, cause it can't find the R.java file supposed to contains its layout.

So I've been doing some research, but I can't figure out how I should do to import my fragment's UI in a library project. My first thought was to create the UI in pure java code, but it's an incredible pain in the...

Thanks for your help and attention :)

Comment: did you forgot to copy the XML layout to the library project?

Comment: @Budius What do you mean by that? I let my xml layout in the res/folder of my library project, should I copy it somewhere else?  I'd like to avoid having to copy it to my final project using the library, this seems weird to have a library and a its ressource in two separated file... if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

My first comment I was just wondering if you started writing the fragment on the final project and midway through decided to change it into the library project. Ignore that.

Now to answer your question:

I might be wrong, but I guess that's the same reason the ActionBarSherlock is a project instead of a .jar file.

In a nice and easy to sum up: stuff accessed via R.... must be compiled all together. Meaning it cannot be on a separate .jar, but if you have it as a library that is imported and compiled with the final software it should work fine.